# Is it possible to define playbook-global variables in Ansible?

Tags: ansible

I have a large Ansible playbook where Docker images are built when running it. I am using an increasing number as the tag to version them. Currently, I have to specify this in every `hosts:` section.

I know there are global variables but from what I found by searching for "ansible" "global variables", they have to defined outside of the playbook. Is it possible to define global variables which are global for the playbook?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

If the tag/version you are using is applicable to all hosts, then using [group_vars/all](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/intro_inventory.html#groups-of-groups-and-group-variables) is a viable option.

If the revision numbers are specific to each host entries in a host_vars/host_name file might be better.

If you want to read and initial var and then increment it after each play that becomes a bit more difficult to persist that information across plays  (or each -hosts as you say) in the playbook.  For example if you were looking to deploy N docker instances you might do some dynamic inventory magic like this:

```
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
  - add_host: name=docker_{{item}} groups="dockers,other" tag={{item}}
    with_sequence: start={{ext_def_start}} count={{ext_def_num}}


- hosts: docker_*
  tasks:
  - debug: var=tag
```

Comment: I wanted to have the variables in the playbook because I have it in Git. I then resort to sharing the inventory files with the variables, and have to adapt it. I wanted the variables in the playbook because once everything is all set up, they don't change, but the hosts in the inventory might.

Comment: The way ansible handles variables is a bit clunky but it is understandable given it's heavy reliance on implicit includes (based on inventory) and the inability to easily share variables across plays.  As my example shows, I've resorted to using inventory modules to push data into inventory vars.  Fact (see set_fact module) persist across plays but they are on a per host basis.  Keep in mind you can always write a quick script (eg python) to generate a dynamic inventory, including vars and grouping, that looks exactly the way you want.

Comment: I was thinking of something like this (writing a script that generates an inventory) by myself, I think I will do that. The playbook is for setting up a basic Hadoop cluster with Spark/YARN support, Cassandra database and Zeppelin, and I might write a script that first asks the user to enumerate all hosts and then set which hosts should house which service.

Comment: `group_vars/all` is not exactly global. Normally global means that it is shared and it exists only one instance of the variable. But `group_vars/all` is not shared but duplicated for each host. If one hosts modifies a variable from `group_vars/all` the other hosts will not see the change.

Answer (score 22):

Ansible has a default `all` group that, funnily enough, contains all the hosts in the inventory file.

As such you can do like with any host groups and provide [group_vars](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/intro_inventory.html#groups-of-groups-and-group-variables) for the host group.

As shown in the previous link these can be defined directly in the inventory file or they can be contained in a separate file named after the group in a `group_vars` directory at the same directory level as the inventory file.

An example directory structure might then look something like:

```
-ansible
 |--inventory
 |  |--group_vars
 |  |  |--all
 |  |  |--dev
 |  |  |--test
 |  |  |--prod
 |  |  |--webservers
 |  |  |--databases
 |  |--dev
 |  |--test
 |  |--prod
 |--roles
  ...
```

Your dev inventory file might then look something like:

```
[dev:children]
webservers
databases

[webservers]
web1.dev
web2.dev

[databases]
database-master.dev
database-slave.dev
```

All of these hosts will now pick up any host specific config (that could be defined either in line or, just like with group_vars can be put into a host_vars folder) and also config for the specific groups they are in such as `webservers` and then the groups they also inherit from such as `dev` but also, by default, `all`.

This can then be used to configure things in a coarser way than per host.

Things such as NTP servers may want to be defined in all, while DNS servers may want to be defined at the environment level (if your network is segmented into dev, test and production they may need different DNS servers setting in `/etc/resolv.conf`) while different types of servers may have different configurations around things such as lists of packages to be installed. Finally, some things may need to be host specific such as setting the MySQL server id in a replication group.

If, instead, you only want to define playbook global settings rather than across the inventory (and so could be accessed by other playbooks) then you simply need a `vars` block in your [play](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_variables.html#variables-defined-in-a-playbook) definition like so:

```
- hosts: webservers
  vars:
    http_port: 80
  tasks:
    - name: Task1 to be ran against all the webservers
      ...
```

As mentioned before, you can always use the `all` group here too:

```
- hosts: all
  vars:
    ntp_pool:
      - ntp1.domain
      - ntp2.domain
  tasks:
    - name: Task1 to be ran against all the servers
      ...
```

In general though, I would strongly recommend using roles to structure what things are ran against certain hosts and then using the inventory to explain what servers are what type and then use a group_vars dir at the inventory level to contain all the variables for those groups of hosts. Doing things this way will help you keep things in sensible places and allow you to easily reuse your code base.

Comment: Hmm, putting a `[{hosts: 'all', vars: {test: 'hello'}}, {hosts: 'web': roles: [...]}` When I get into the roles after the setup phase on 'all', I still get `a variable that is undefined.` error :(

Comment: @ThorSummoner I'm getting that too. I think that those variables are only valid for a task called inside that host group.

Comment: If you're interested, I'll write up my solution.

Comment: From what i understand they are not global variables as such, its more of a templating system to define per host variables. ie for every variable defined in all, there are n instances of it, one for each of the n hosts in the inventory. This is not the same as having a single global variable that can be manipulated at run time.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, global vars are possible like this,

sample splunk setup playbook

```
splunk/
   setup_splunk_playbook.yaml
   roles/base
           /tasks/main.yaml
           /tasks/install.yaml
         search_head
           /tasks/configure.yaml
         indexer
           /tasks/configure.yaml
         some_other_role
           /tasks/some_task.yaml
   hosts
   config.yaml
```

Place your vars into config.yaml

*cat splunk/config.yaml*

```
--- 
# global Splunk variables
splunk_version: 7.0.0
```

in your playbook, include the Roles

*cat setup_splunk_playbook.yaml*

```
- hosts: "search_heads"  
  become_user: root
  become: true
  gather_facts: true

  roles:
    - base
    - search_head
```

in your Role, include the Global Vars inside a Task

*cat roles/base/tasks/main.yaml*

```
---
# install Splunk Base

- name: include vars
  include_vars: "{{ playbook_dir }}/config.yaml"

- include: install.yaml
```

vars are accessible in tasks now,

cat roles/base/tasks/install.yaml

```
- name: echo version
  debug: splunk version is {{ splunk_version }}
```

Comment: Does not work for using variables in the "hosts:" property.

Answer (score 1):

*I know this might not answer OP's query exactly, but for people googling to set global variables(lists/arrays) so that they don't have to set them in each task this might be pretty handy.*

Its surprisingly simple, Say you have a list of domains that you need to pass, I named the variable goofy just to signify that it could be anything.

```
- hosts: [yourhostlistgoeshere]
  remote_user: root
  vars:
    domainslisto:
       - site1.com
       - website2.xyz

....



  tasks:
    - name: copy vhosts
      template: src=virtualhost.conf dest=/etc/apache2/sites-available/{{ item }}.conf
      with_items: "{{ domainslisto }}"

    - name: a2ensite {{ item }}
      command: a2ensite {{ item }}
      with_items: "{{ domainslisto }}"
```

Comment: Works only for a single play per playbook.