# Ansible: want to use the var in hosts

Tags: ansible

I'm using the Ansile 2.0.1.0 And Docker.
I want to connect to the container to create a Docker container in Ansbile.
Also the name of the container want to manage in the variable.
But When executing I get error message.

main.yml

```
- name: data container
  hosts: localhost
  roles:
    - role: docker
  tasks:
    - debug: var=docker_hostname
- name: hogefuga
  hosts: "{{docker_hostname}}"
  connection: docker
  roles:
    - hogefuga
```

role/dockers/tasks/main.yml

```
- name: Create Container
  shell: "docker run --name={{docker_hostname}}"

- name: host add DockerContainer
  add_host: name={{ docker_hostname }} group="dockers"
```

group_vars/all

```
docker_hostname: hoge
```

Error Message

```
TASK [debug] *******************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "docker_hostname": "hoge"
}
ERROR! 'docker_hostname' is undefined
```

I'm guessing that it for using the var to hosts.
How can I fix the error?

Comment: My English is not so good,Sorry. But thank you for reading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found Anser.
[Is it possible to define playbook-global variables in Ansible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33126156/is-it-possible-to-define-playbook-global-variables-in-ansible)

I did not know that can set the group_name to hosts.

```
- name: hogefuga
  hosts: dockers
  connection: docker
  roles:
    - hogefuga
```